# How can I use dropout in Conv Layer to drop activation maps in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, dropout

I am trying to add dropout in convolutional layers(although it seems people dont do this a lot).

According to cs231n, they recommended to drop the activation maps instead of units in all activation maps（I consider this somehow make sense, because each activation maps are extracting the same feature in different positions）.

In tensorflow, I can't find any API can directly do this, so how can I do this?
This is my first time asking a question in StackOverflow, and I will appreciate for  advices and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with the available dropout functions via the `noise_shape` argument. E.g. using the `layers` API:

```
x = tf.layers.dropout(x, noise_shape=[batch_size, 1, 1, features])
```

This would be for 2D convolution and `channels_last` format. We only generate a single noise value for image width/height which will be broadcast over the image dimensions. However, we still generate a different noise value for each feature/activation map.

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Comment: Great! If this solves your question, consider upvoting and accepting the answer so other people can see it more easily.